# "Άγεωμέτρητος μηδεὶς εἰσίτω" in Latin

Tags: mathematics, plato, philosophy, greek-to-latin-translation

Legend has it that the gable of Plato's Academy read: "Let no one enter who is ignorant of geometry" ("Άγεωμέτρητος μηδεὶς εἰσίτω").

How do you render that in classical Latin? Here are two possibilities I've come up with, I'd love to read what you think.

> qui geometriam nescit non intret

> nemo nisi geometrae intret

Edit: For example, do I need to add "huc" or can I use "intret" without a complement or in+acc?

Comment: Given that "geometria" is a Greek borrowing already, are you opposed to borrowing "ageometretus" too?

Comment: @Draconis *Geometria* was borrowed by the Romans, but I don't think *ageometr-* anything was. I'm also surprised this wasn't already translated into Latin at some point. Perhaps some medieval philosopher?

Comment: I think you want the singular *geometres* rather than the plural *geometrae* in your second option. Other than that, I think both your translations are good.

Comment: @Draconis I have mixed feelings about "ageometretus" since AFAIK it is not attested in classical Latin, but it might be a good reference to the original, what would be the complete phrase?

Comment: @cmw I was also surprised to find nothing online!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the following possibility is [attested](https://books.google.fr/books?id=y8lBAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA390&lpg=PA390&dq=%22Qui%20Geometiam%20nefcit,%20huc%20non%20intret.%22&source=bl&ots=jnDBdgManL) in the 17th century in "Wunder-Spiegel oder Göttliche Wunderwerck" by Kybler:

> Qui Geometriam neſcit, huc non intret.

So pretty much what I suggested, apart from "huc"!
Thanks for your comments.